# Importing pre-ADT17 Android project to Eclipse with ADT17

Tags: android, adt

I am having problems importing some of my older Android apps that have been created with an ADT version < 17.

I have installed all the latest Android Tools and ADT Plugin (17). I'm fully aware of how ADT17 is handling libraries.

My problem:
Eclipse doesn't create the "Android Dependencies" library. It simply isn't there (not even an entry in the .classpath file).

Any idea how I can convert my old projects to work with the new ADT?

Comment: i have even tried to remove the project from eclipse, delete .classpath, .project files and then readd using "New Android Project" "Use existing source". Same error :(

Comment: On some other project the "Android Dependencies" entry is added to the classpath but it has a hint "(unbound)". What does it mean?

Comment: You already tried this: Right click on your project in eclipse -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties ?

Comment: yes, first thing i did right after Project/Clean and close/open...

Answer (score 0):

Try these two approaches?

1. Generate a "libs" directory in your projects (same level with 'src','res', etc.), copy all the jars you need to that dir. Then clean and rebuild the project.
2. Open .classpath file, change (or generate) the line below

   < classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>

   to

   < classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>

   Then refresh, clean and rebuild the project.